# Parse Specific iOS Push Targeting

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification

I am trying to send a push to a specific PFUser. I have a pointer to the User class inside Parse for each PFInstallation. I have done this before, but for some reason it's failing.

```
PFUser *gameOwner = [gameObject objectForKey:@"Defender"];

PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:gameOwner];

PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"New Game Started From %@!", [PFUser currentUser][@"Name"]], @"alert",
                      @"Increment", @"badge",
                      @"default", @"sound",
                      nil];
[push setQuery:pushQuery];
[push setData:data];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

Any clues what is wrong?

Comment: Try with making `push` a property, it may be released before actual execution

Comment: Check if `gameOwner` is not nil.

Comment: gameOwner is not nil, tried making push a property but the same, on Parse it's showing a Push but just 0 pushes sent.

Comment: Are you sure that problem is in sending? Do you receive messages sent from parse server?

Comment: I get Parse not matching any queries

Comment: try to use [push sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) method to log the error